# Too much information displayed with awesome_print

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `awesome_print`, and when I run a command in which awesome_print is invoked, the following result is returned:

```
 irb(main):002:0> ap User.find(1)
    ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 1]]
    #<User:0x57d9650> {
        :id←[0;37m => ←[0m←[1;34m1←[0m,
        :name←[0;37m => ←[0m←[0;33m"aa"←[0m,
        :email←[0;37m => ←[0m←[0;33m"aa"←[0m,
        :created_at←[0;37m => ←[0m←[0;32mTue, 26 May 2015 15:13:51 UTC +00:00←[0m,
        :updated_at←[0;37m => ←[0m←[0;32mTue, 26 May 2015 15:13:51 UTC +00:00←[0m
```

However, I notice information like `←[0;37m` is displayed.

I have two questions :

- What do things like `←[0;37m` mean?
- How do you delete the above notation in order to print results like:

  ```
  :id => 1,
  :first_name => "aa",
  :last_name => "aa"
  :created_at => Tue, 26 May 2015 15:13:51 UTC +00:00
  ```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which awesome_print version you are using?

Comment: try `ap.logger User.find(1), :info`.......

Comment: What OS? If you're on Windows, use this utility for console: https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon And you'll see colored output.

Comment: Windows, thank you i work actually on default console so i will check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0;37m`-type content are ANSI color codes - it's possible your current setup isn't rendering them properly.

You should be able to remove those notations by modifying the default color setting in awesome_print. A file, `awesome_print.rb`, can be created in the *config/initializers* directory.

config/initializers/awesome_print.rb:

```
AwesomePrint.defaults = {
  :plain => true # do not use colors
  # any further default settings you wish to specify
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but in witch file I put this code? gemfile?

Comment: It goes inside of your *config/initializers*. Updated answer with these details. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using colors you might as well not use `awesome_print` gem. There is ruby built in plain text pretty print.

```
require 'pp'
pp User.find(1)
```

You are probably running this on windows machine, if so check out [ANSI color codes for Windows Command Prompt](https://serverfault.com/questions/106028/how-to-enable-ansi-escape-codes-in-windows-cmd)